# Question involving normal and directrix of parabola

Tags: contest-math, conic-sections

> Three normals are drawn from a point $P(1,1)$ to a parabola and let $A,B,C$ be feet of perpendiculars with $A=(0,0)$ and $B=(3,-1),$ find the slope of directrix. If equation of parabola is$ (x-a)^2+(y+b)^2=\frac{(x+cy-8)^2}{10}$, find $a+2b+c$

**My Attempt:**

Sum of ordinates of feet of normals is zero. Therefore, let $C=(h,1)$.

Also, second part of the question implies focus is $(a,-b)$ and directrix is $x+cy-8=0$.

A solution exists on [toppr website](https://www.toppr.com/ask/question/three-normals-are-drawn-from-a-point-p1-1-to-a-parabola-and-let-a/) but I don't understand how they calculated $a$.

I know the semi-latus rectum is the harmonic mean of the segments of focal chord but don't know how to use that here.

Also, is there any other way solve this question?

**Edit:** In the answer below, are we rejecting $c=3$? Why?

Comment: For $c=3$, the parabola has a point $C(h,1)$. See [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%280%E2%88%92a%29%5E2+%2B%280%2Bb%29%5E2+%3D+%28%28%E2%88%928%29%5E2%29%2F%2810%29+and+%283%E2%88%92a%29%5E2+%2B%28-1%2Bb%29%5E2+%3D+%28%283-c%E2%88%928%29%5E2%29%2F%2810%29+and+%28h%E2%88%92a%29%5E2+%2B%281%2Bb%29%5E2+%3D+%28%28h%2Bc%E2%88%928%29%5E2%29%2F%2810%29+and+c%3D3). So, I think that we need another condition to eliminate $c=3$.

Comment: @mathlove thanks for the input, I'll try to think about it.

Comment: I found a condition to eliminate $c=3$. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that

$(x-a)^2 + (y+b)^2= \frac{(x+cy-8)^2}{10}$

Taking root both sides and converting it in the form of SP = e*SM (where e is 1 for parabola)

$\sqrt{(x-a)^2+ (y+b)^2}= \frac{(x+cy-8)}{\sqrt10}$

We see that focus is (a,-b) and directrix is x+cy-8=0, as noted by you.

Also, the RHS is the perpendicualr distance of a point from the directrix. Comparing it with

$\frac{ah + bk+ c}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$

[perpendicular distance of (h,k) from the line ax+by+c=0]

$\sqrt{c^2+1} = \sqrt10$

This gives $c^2 = 9$

Also, slope of directrix x+cy-8=0 is $\frac{-1}{c}$ by comparing with y= mx +c

Also, putting (0,0) and (3,-1) in the equation you get

$a^2 + b^2 = 6.4$

$a^2+b^2-6a-2b+10=\frac{c^2+10c+10}{10}$

Write the second equation in terms of $a^2+b^2$ and set equal to first equation. Simplifying, and putting c as -3 we get

3a+b=2
b=2-3a

Substitute in eq 1. We get a= $\frac{12}{5}, b= \frac{4}{5}$

Hence, a+2b+c = 1

**Why not +3?**

To answer that, I did the same but took c as +3. You will get a bit complicated values for a and b. But when you put these values in the parabola's equation, there is no point with the y coordinate 1. Hence, this parabola will not have a point C(h,1).

Comment: So, we are getting slope as $\pm0.33$ but the answer given is $0.33$. Looks like they took $c$ as only $-3$. Any idea why we are eliminating $c=3$?

Comment: Also, on toppr website, I don't know how they calculated $a$. I know that the semi-latus rectum is the harmonic mean of the segments of focal chord. Don't know how to use that here.

Comment: I took a look at their solution, but cannot understand the need for the semi latus rectum property here. Instead, I have edited my answer and done it another way. Also, they got incorrect values for a,b,c. I got different values and verified them using desmos graphing calculator.

Comment: Thanks Vedaansh.

Answer (score 4):

As written in Vedaansh Agarwal's answer, we have
$$c^2=9\tag1$$
$$a^2+b^2=\frac{32}{5}\tag2$$
$$(3-a)^2+(-1+b)^2=\frac{(3-c-8)^2}{10}\tag3$$

Here, Vedaansh Agarwal wrote

> Why not +3? To answer that, I did the same but took c as +3. You will get a bit complicated values for a and b. But when you put these values in the parabola's equation, there is no point with the y coordinate 1. Hence, this parabola will not have a point C(h,1).

However, this is not true.

For $c=3$, the parabola has a point $C(h,1)$. See [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%280%E2%88%92a%29%5E2+%2B%280%2Bb%29%5E2+%3D+%28%28%E2%88%928%29%5E2%29%2F%2810%29+and+%283%E2%88%92a%29%5E2+%2B%28-1%2Bb%29%5E2+%3D+%28%283-c%E2%88%928%29%5E2%29%2F%2810%29+and+%28h%E2%88%92a%29%5E2+%2B%281%2Bb%29%5E2+%3D+%28%28h%2Bc%E2%88%928%29%5E2%29%2F%2810%29+and+c%3D3).

So, this means that we need another condition to eliminate $c=3$.

Differentiating the both sides of
$$(x-a)^2+(y+b)^2=\frac{(x+cy-8)^2}{10}$$
we get
$$2(x-a)+2(y+b)y'=\frac{(x+cy-8)(1+cy')}{5}$$

Substituting $(x,y,y')=(0,0,-1)$, we get
$$-2a-2b=\frac{-8(1-c)}{5}\tag4$$

Solving $(1)(2)(3)(4)$ gives
$$(a,b,c)=\bigg(\frac{12}{5},\frac 45,-3\bigg)$$

Therefore, the slope of directrix is $\color{red}{\frac{1}{3}}$ with $a+2b+c=\color{red}1$.

Comment: That's so wonderful!

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, i might have made a mistake. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Note that the normals at $A,B$ are perpendicular and hence the tangents also are perpendicular. Let them meet at $Q$. So $Q,A,B,P$ is a rectangle where diagonals bisect each other at $M \left(\dfrac{3}{2}, -\dfrac{1}{2} \right)$. So slope of $PM$ = slope of $QM$ = $-3$ and its well known that slope of $QM =$ slope of axis. From this we see that slope of directrix is $-\dfrac{1}{3}$

The tangents meet at $Q(2,-2)$ which lies on the directrix and hence equation of directrix is $x-3y-8=0$. Its now clear from the given equation that the focus is $(a,-b)$ and that $c=-3$.

To obtain the focus we first look at foot of perpendicular from $A(0,0)$ onto the directrix which is $\left(\frac{4}{5}, -\frac{12}{5} \right)$

This also happens to be the reflection of focus across the tangent $QA \equiv x+y=0$. Thus the focus is obtained as $S\left( \frac{12}{5},-\frac{4}{5}\right)$ so that $a=\frac{12}{5}, b = \frac{4}{5}$